# Finding person who ate least in C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've written code which lets you see which person ate the most and the least. However, my code isn't working for finding who ate the least. I was able to find who ate the most and I tried using the opposite of that code for finding who ate the least. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int people[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    int pancakes[10];
    int m = 0; // most pancakes eaten
    int l = 1; // least pancakes eaten
    int mp = 0; // most people
    int lp = 1; // least people
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
    cout << people[x] << " ate: ";
        cin >> pancakes[x];
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        if (pancakes[x] > m)
        {
            m = pancakes[x];
            mp = people[x];
        }
        else if (pancakes[x] <= l)
        {
            l = pancakes[x];
            lp = people[x];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << mp << " person ate most: " << m << "  pancakes\n";
    cout << lp << " person ate least: " << l << " pancakes\n";
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. I can use just these:

- variables, data types, and numerical operators
- basic input/output
- logic (if statements, switch statements)
- loops (for, while, do-while)
- arrays

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @AndreasDM nope, I'm coding for free time, like hobby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either initialize `l` to large number, or better make `l` to be some value from the array like: `l = pancakes[0]`. Add that line below  the first for so something like this:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        cout << people[x] << " ate: ";
        cin >> pancakes[x];
    }

m = pancakes[0];
l = pancakes[0];
...
```

`m` and `l` should be actual values from the `pancakes` array, not some random values.

Your code didn't work because you set `l` to `1`, and only if someone ate less then 1 pancake the code inside the last `if` statement will be executed.

Comment: I need which person, not the number of least eaten pancakes.

Comment: @Ciklopaz so you say that `lp` doesn't give you correct value?

Comment: Yes, I don;t know why. I restarted program, thought it was a bug.

Comment: @Ciklopaz I've edited the code, and this gives me the correct result.